# How to fill the page with an image?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to paste a picture in MS Word, the picture should fill the width of the page between the margins (that is, fill the entire width **between the left and right margin** of the page).

Is there a way to make it 100% width, without manual adjustment?

The scale ratio should be conserved.

Comment: What do you mean by "without manual adjustment"?

Comment: I mean without the mouse approximate adjustment... I want 100%, not 25cm or manually dragging the picture

Answer (score 1):

Figure out the width of the page between the margins. 
You can do this in “Page Setup” or by looking at the ruler. 
For example, I use 8½”×11” paper with one-inch margins,
so I have 6½” between the margins.

Then,

- paste your picture,
- right-click on it,
- go into “Size and Position…”, and
- set the “Width” to the desired value (e.g., 6.5).

Comment: so, there is no way to make it 100%, I need to do calculations, check sizes, and if the page change, or margins changes, I need to recalculate manually

Comment: there is not enough to set the width, there is need that the position of the picture to be as well "0 from the left margin"...

Comment: (1) OK, yes 8½”−1”−1” *is* a calculation. Most people can do it in their heads. Even if you need to use a calculator, you need to do it only once — unless your page width varies within your document. If it does, you should have mentioned that in your question.  (2) It is my experience that a pasted image that is set to the width of the page between the margins locks in to both margins (i.e., 0” away). Perhaps we are using different versions of Microsoft Word. Perhaps you’re doing something that is not clear to me from my understanding of your question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Perhaps you want or need a VBA solution.  It would be helpful if you [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1652320/edit) your question to specify your operating environment, processes/procedures, and constraints more clearly and thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your comments. I don't need VBA, I don't need manual calculation (8-1-1), I just need to paste a picture that would take 100% printable page width... If that is not possible, that is also an answer... I mean, my desired value is "100%"